# Spring Test - JavaConfig per Project

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-java-config

I have various unit test classes in my system, and they all extend a centralized test class called `AbstractContextTest`. Said abstract superclass generally looks like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@TestExecutionListeners({DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class, DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class})
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"/TestContext.xml"})
public class AbstractContextTest {
  // Various utility methods that would be useful in a unit test.
  ...
}
```

The important thing to note here is the `@ContextConfiguration` line. It uses the `locations` attribute to load the test Application Context stored in an XML file. It works by using a relative path, which allows me to do the following:

1. I place my `AbstractContextTest` superclass in its own project.
2. I configure my other projects to have my `AbstractContextTest` project as a test-level dependency.
3. I place an identically-named `TestContext.xml` in each of my projects' test resources.
4. When I run all my unit tests, each project uses its local `TestContext.xml` due to the relative pathing.
5. All is right with the world.

So now for the actual question: I wish to move on from the halcyon days of Spring XML Application Contexts into the brave new world of Spring JavaConfigs. Is there an equivalent to my relative path solution in this paradigm? If so, how do I pull it off?

Comment: For your world is better a config file strategy instead a class config, because @ContextConfiguration want a reference to a class. You should play with hierarchies. I suggest you the first way considered that your world works fine. [see tutorial](http://spring.io/blog/2011/06/21/spring-3-1-m2-testing-with-configuration-classes-and-profiles)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that was ever curious, I'm going to go ahead and show the correct solution that I ended up with. I'm pretty sure this is what chrylis was describing, but he abjectly refused to show an example of it or explain it in any way.

So here's the `abstract` superclass itself:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@TestExecutionListeners(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class)
@ContextConfiguration(loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
public abstract class AbstractContextTest {
  @Configuration
  @ComponentScan(basePackages = "my.package.name.test",
                 includeFilters = @Filter(type = FilterType.ANNOTATION,
                                          value = Configuration.class))
  static class ContextConfiguration {}
}
```

Then in your other projects, under `src/test/java`, in a package matching the scanned package in your `abstract` superclass (in this case, "`my.package.name.test`"), you have a context class you can name whatever you like. I chose "`TestContext`" for this example:

```
package my.package.name.test;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "package.under.test")
public class TestContext {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can place identically-named `@Configuration` classes in each project's `src/test/java` and get the same effect. It's likely, though, that at this point you're being overly clever, and I would recommend having a separate intermediate abstract base test class for each project.

Comment: But what would I have to do in my `AbstractContextTest` to have it resolve those `@Configuration` classes? Are you saying that I can remove `@ContextConfiguration` entirely and it will just instantly work using some sort of black magic?

Comment: No, but you can use the exact same class name, just like you use the same name for the XML file.

Comment: That would make it `@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestContext.class})`, which means that `AbstractContextTest` would have an import for the `TestContext` class in order to refer to it. This would necessitate that the `AbstractContext` project have a dependency on every single other project in order to import all of their individual versions of the `TestContext` class. Considering that all of those projects would already have the `AbstractContextTest` project as a dependency, this would result in a giant web of circular dependencies. So no, I'm pretty sure that wouldn't work at all.

Comment: Nope. Java resolves classes by full name, and that's all. Each module would have its own version with the exact same name. This sort of thing, though, is why I said it's overly clever and not the best option.

Comment: I feel like you're just trolling me at this point. You say "Just do this thing!" And I ask "How do you do that thing?" And you respond "Just do the thing!" You're going in circles and not actually showing me how I would do the thing you're talking about. Edit your answer and show me an example. I have never in my life seen any Java code that could reference a particular type of object from another package (other than `Object` itself) without having an `import` statement at the top of the file for that type.

Comment: I'm not saying you can't import it. I *am* saying that the actual `foo.BarConfig.class` file isn't resolved until runtime, and that the ones made available in the test classpath on different modules could be completely separate code. This is why you can get weird `NoClassDefFoundError`s when you have the wrong version of a library pulled in; the name matches, but the Java linker can't make it all work.

Comment: "I'm not saying you can't import it." I never accused you of saying it. *I'm* the one saying you can't import it, because "it" is 20 different things in 20 different projects that would result in 20 different circular dependencies if you tried. If you do `@ContextConfiguration(class = {TestContext.class})`, and you do not have an `import` statement for `TestContext`, that is a *compilation error*. It *will. Not. Function*. You may be talking about doing something else, but I wouldn't know, because you refuse to give an example or actually explain how to do what you're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

The `@ContextConfiguration` has a `classes` attribute that allows you to specify a Java config file instead of the XML context. However, since we are dealing with classes you need to add the class with Java config you must add it to your imports. Consequently, you cannot declare `@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestConfig.class)` in your test project, because it will not compile without a concrete class (the fact that you will create different implementations in your downstream projects later on does not help the `AbstractContextTest` project to compile). This is a good thing, since it means that you have to be explicit about your Java configs in the tests. After all, there is a reason why you have created separate projects in the first place.

Personally, I prefer to have the two extra lines with the Spring specific annotations in relevant test. The first line makes it clear that it is an Spring based test (as opposed to a general jUnit test), and the second line tells me where I find the relevant application context(s):

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestConfig.class)
public class DownStreamProjectTest extends AbstractContextTest {

    // tests
}
```

Side note, I would advice against putting the `DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener` in a generic test class hierarchy. It will cause Spring to re-create the entire application context for each test, which will significantly increase the turn around time of your test suite.